# Docker container update --memory didn't work as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, archlinux

Good morning all,

In the process of trying to train myself in Docker, I'm having trouble.

I created a docker container from a wordpress image, via docker compose.

```
[root@vps672971 ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
57bb123aa365        wordpress:latest                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 hours ago        Up 2                0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp                       royal-by-jds-wordpress-container
```

I would like to allocate more memory to this container, however after the execution of the following command, the information returned by **docker stats** are not correct.

```
docker container update --memory 3GB --memory-swap 4GB royal-by-jds-wordpress-container

docker stats

CONTAINER ID        NAME                                 CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
57bb123aa365        royal-by-jds-wordpress-container     0.01%               9.895MiB / 1.896GiB   0.51%               2.68kB / 0B         0B / 0B             6
```

I also tried to request API engine to retrieve information about my container, but the limitation displayed is not correct either.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.21/containers/royal-by-jds-wordpress-container/stats

    [...]
    "memory_stats":{
      "usage":12943360,
      "max_usage":12955648,
      "stats":{},
      "limit":2035564544
    },
    [...]
```

It seems that the modification of the memory allocated to the container didn't work.

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Maxence

Comment: You don't use docker for mac or windows, do you?

Comment: Exactly, I installed an arch linux distribution on a VPS.

Comment: Maybe VPS has some external memory restrictions? (2 Gb or smth)

Comment: Looking more closely at the VPS disk space, however, it would appear that there is 15 GB of available space on the server. Is it possible that the limitation comes from a default configuration of Docker?

Comment: I meant the limit of RAM, not of disk space

Comment: There are a number of container options that can only be set at startup time, and you'll need to routinely delete and recreate the container (for example to update the underlying PHP environment).  Even if you can change _this_ option in place, I'd suggest trying to delete and recreate the container with the new option.